# How do you store 2 different value from the same input

Tags: c

I'm still fairly new to coding. How do I store the different value from the same input variable? The input is from a keypad, so I want to keep the input when a button is pressed. The user will press 3 numbers and store the value to 3 different variables.

Example,

`````
num_one = keypad();
num_two = keypad();
num_three = keypad();

unsigned char keypad()
{
LATB = 0b11100000; // Column 1 set to zero
Delay1KTCYx(2); // Debounce delay

if (PORTBbits.RB0==0) // Check Row 1 is it Key 1?
{return 1;} // If so display key 1

if (PORTBbits.RB1==0) // Check for next key in Row 2, is it key 4?
{return 4;} // If so display key 4

if (PORTBbits.RB2==0) // Check for next key in Row 3, is it key 7?
{return 7;} // If so display key 7
}````
`````

Answer (score 0):

What you have outlined would work, given that the three variables are actually defined somewhere, e.g.:

```
unsigned char key1, key2, key3;
```

in the global scope.

However, *logically* it seems that `keypad()` doesn't wait for an actual key press, it just sans and returns the first key found. If no key is down when the function is called, it's not clear what it returns, and possibly the three variables will be filled with "garbage" (or `0`).

Comment: Yes, ````keypad()```` will just scan and return a value when a key is pressed. This cause the 3 variable to always be the same value. Is there a way to give the variable a value individually?